# Table is showing weird in PDF if table width is more than pdf width using JsPDF Angular library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

In html have text, table and plotly chart, but when i export pdf from HTMl then table is not showing with all column in PDF and also not showing Plotly chart using below code.

```
const doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
const specialElementHandlers = {
  '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
   return true;
  }
};
const pdfTable = this.conversationsEl.nativeElement;
doc.fromHTML(pdfTable, 10, 10, {
  width: 540,
  elementHandlers: specialElementHandlers,
}, ()=> {
  doc.save(`Report-${currentDate}` + '.pdf');
}, {
  top:10,
  bottom:10,
  left:10,
  right:10
});
```